# Testing of a first stage using dummy upper stages?

Tags: rockets, testing, first-stage

The first stage of the Saturn I was tested three times using dummy upper stages filled with ballast water, see [Project Highwater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Highwater) and this [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/21515/project-high-water-and-the-lightning-like-radio-disturbances-it-caused). The first two flight tests of the Saturn V (SA-501 and SA-502, Apollo 4 and 6) were done with all three stages fuelled. See also [Saturn I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_I) and [Saturn V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_V)

Are there other rockets with two or more stages that have been flight tested using a first stage with dummy upper stages at first?

Comment: I believe the all-up Saturn V test plan was very unusual at the time, with stage-at-a-time testing being the norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Europa 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europa_%28rocket%29): lots of tests of the first stage with dummy upper stages, and of individual stages (i.e. a launch of the second stage only, etc.).

Comment: Europa 1, there were a lot of tests but no success. Are there other rockets with more success like Saturn 1?